# Javascript Chrome Tainted canvases may not be exported but firefox is not error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, canvas, export

Svg image convert canvas to png but chrome browser is error: Tainted canvases may not be exported But Firefox is not error and image save and download.
my svg object:

I think error source can be foreignobject.because I remove this object,chrome not error.it has to stay svg inside

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="drawcontentssvg" width="410" height="230" viewBox="-100 -70 410 230">
<defs><filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="dhx_text_background">
<feFlood flood-color="white"></feFlood>
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"></feComposite>
</filter></defs>
<g id="shapeImg" shape-rendering="crispedges">
<g transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0,105,45)" dhx_id="1">
<rect class="dhx_item_shape" id="1" height="90" width="210" fill="white" rx="1" ry="1" stroke="#FF9800" stroke-width="1"></rect>
<foreignObject overflow="hidden" transform="translate(0 0)" width="210" height="90"><div class="shape_content" style="height: 90px;">
<div style="text-align: center; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; font-weight: 500; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38); font-size: 14px; line-height: 17px; margin-top: 25px; white-space: nowrap; text-transform: uppercase;">fsfsfsfsf</div>
<div style="text-align: center;"></div></div>
</foreignObject>
<rect height="3.5" width="210" stroke="#FF9800" fill="#FF9800" stroke-width="1"></rect>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with getting canvas dataURI from svg with foreignObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897039/problems-with-getting-canvas-datauri-from-svg-with-foreignobject)

Comment: Firefox supports this, Chrome does not as you've already discovered. What else can we tell you?

Comment: thank u for helps  Kaiido and Robert Longson